# Is there a Python equivalent of Groovy/Grails for Java

Tags: python, django, grails, groovy, jython

I'm thinking of something like Jython/Jango? Does this exist? Or does Jython allow you to do everything-Python in Java including Django (I'm not sure how Jython differs from Python)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://wiki.python.org/jython/DjangoOnJython

Answer (score 3):

"I'm not sure how Jython differs from Python"

http://www.jython.org/Project/

> Jython is an implementation of the
>   high-level, dynamic, object-oriented
>   language Python seamlessly integrated
>   with the Java platform.

http://docs.python.org/reference/introduction.html#alternate-implementations

> Python implemented in Java. This
>   implementation can be used as a
>   scripting language for Java
>   applications, or can be used to create
>   applications using the Java class
>   libraries. It is also often used to
>   create tests for Java libraries. More
>   information can be found at the Jython
>   website.

Answer (score 2):

http://turbogears.org/

might be closer to what you are looking for